# Robot FW : Builtin module : Set Suite Variable : How to overwrite the newly created variable to in the new scope?

Tags: robotframework, built-in

Acc.to [Variable scopes](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-scopes), we have Global Scope, Test Suite Scope, Test Case scope and Local Scope.

Referring to the [Set Suite Variable documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable):

> If a variable already exists within **the new scope**, its value will be overwritten.

My goal is to write a simple code snippet, which demonstrates this sentence in practice. **This is the technical problem**.

To be able to fully implement the technical goal, **the new scope** and **current scope** need an explanation. For example, how does current/new scope relate to Global Scope, Test Suite Scope, Test Case scope and Local Scope?

Comment: Please read the [ask] section. In my opinion this question has 6 distinct questions and not all of them relate to a technical problem. Please [edit] your question to a single technical topic.

Comment: I simplified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you're asking, but I think the following tests might illustrate the sentence *"If a variable already exists within the new scope, its value will be overwritten."*

First, this test creates a variable named `${var}` in the test scope of the first test. A second test verifies that the variable isn't visible outside of the original scope.

The third test starts the same as the first test, creating a test-scoped variable. It then calls Set suite variable which overwrites the variable that is in the test scope of the third test.

Finally, a fourth test shows that the variable is now available to every test in the suite since the variable exists in the suite scope.

```
*** Test cases ***
Example 1
    # Set a variable in a test scope
    Set test variable  ${var}  test
    Should be equal    ${var}  test

Example 2
    # Verifies that the variable from the first test
    # is not available in this new test scope
    Variable should not exist  ${var}

Example 3
    # Set a variable in the test scope
    Set test variable  ${var}  test
    Should be equal    ${var}  test

    # Set a suite variable that has the same name as the local variable
    Set suite variable  ${var}  suite

    # Even though we set it as a suite scope, it overwrites the local
    # variable of the same name
    Should be equal  ${var}  suite

Example 4
    # Verify the suite variable from the previous test is visible
    # in this new test scope
    Should be equal  ${var}  suite
```

Comment: Relating the "Example 3" test with the documentation "If a variable already exists within the new scope, its value will be overwritten.", i think the documentation has a bug. The better statement could be "If a variable already exists within the test case scope, its value will be overridden". Do you agree?

Comment: @HKN: I think the current wording is correct. My example just does a poor job of illustrating it. I think you're overthinking this - the keyword works pretty much exactly as described, it sets a suite variable to a value. It either changes an existing variable or creates a new one.